# Group by consecutive values in one column and select the earliest and latest date for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to group by consecutive values in `col1` and for each group, select the earliest date and hour from `col2` and `col3` and the latest date and hour from `col4` and `col5`.

Here is my data:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 2021-07-03 | 17:08 | 2021-07-04 | 10:41 |
| 1 | b | 2021-07-10 | 04:14 | 2021-07-11 | 04:32 |
| 2 | c | 2021-07-13 | 02:03 | 2021-07-14 | 00:45 |
| 3 | d | 2021-07-14 | 21:23 | 2021-07-15 | 02:59 |
| 4 | d | 2021-07-15 | 04:05 | 2021-07-15 | 09:41 |
| 5 | e | 2021-07-17 | 13:50 | 2021-07-18 | 08:49 |
| 6 | a | 2021-07-18 | 10:51 | 2021-07-18 | 12:27 |
| 7 | a | 2021-07-18 | 13:55 | 2021-07-19 | 06:26 |
| 8 | f | 2021-09-20 | 22:36 | 2021-09-20 | 23:19 |
| 9 | f | 2021-09-21 | 23:45 | 2021-09-23 | 10:12 |

Expected output:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 2021-07-03 | 17:08 | 2021-07-04 | 10:41 |
| 1 | b | 2021-07-10 | 04:14 | 2021-07-11 | 04:32 |
| 2 | c | 2021-07-13 | 02:03 | 2021-07-14 | 00:45 |
| 3 | d | 2021-07-14 | 21:23 | 2021-07-15 | 09:41 |
| 4 | e | 2021-07-17 | 13:50 | 2021-07-18 | 08:49 |
| 5 | a | 2021-07-18 | 10:51 | 2021-07-19 | 06:26 |
| 6 | f | 2021-09-20 | 22:36 | 2021-09-23 | 10:12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution expects the dates to be sorted from the earliest to the latest, as in the provided example data.

```py
from itertools import groupby
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(
        """col1 col2    col3    col4    col5
a   2021-07-03  17:08   2021-07-04  10:41
b   2021-07-10  04:14   2021-07-11  04:32
c   2021-07-13  02:03   2021-07-14  00:45
d   2021-07-14  21:23   2021-07-15  02:59
d   2021-07-15  04:05   2021-07-15  09:41
e   2021-07-17  13:50   2021-07-18  08:49
a   2021-07-18  10:51   2021-07-18  12:27
a   2021-07-18  13:55   2021-07-19  06:26
f   2021-09-20  22:36   2021-09-20  23:19
f   2021-09-21  23:45   2021-09-23  10:12
"""
    ),
    delim_whitespace=True,
    header=0,
)

# Group by consecutive values in col1
groups = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(df["col1"].values.tolist())]
group_end_indices = pd.Series(len(g) for g in groups).cumsum()
group_start_indices = (group_end_indices - group_end_indices.diff(1)).fillna(0).astype(int)

filtered_df = []
for start_ix, end_ix in zip(group_start_indices, group_end_indices):
    group = df.iloc[start_ix:end_ix]
    if group.shape[0] > 1:
        group.iloc[0][["col4", "col5"]] = group.iloc[-1][["col4", "col5"]]
    filtered_df.append(group.iloc[0])
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_df).reset_index(drop=True)
print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```bash
  col1        col2   col3        col4   col5
0    a  2021-07-03  17:08  2021-07-04  10:41
1    b  2021-07-10  04:14  2021-07-11  04:32
2    c  2021-07-13  02:03  2021-07-14  00:45
3    d  2021-07-14  21:23  2021-07-15  09:41
4    e  2021-07-17  13:50  2021-07-18  08:49
5    a  2021-07-18  10:51  2021-07-19  06:26
6    f  2021-09-20  22:36  2021-09-23  10:12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that these are datetimes and use pandas groupby to select the earlier dates from col2+col3 and later dates from col4+col5 for each group.

```py
filtered_df = (
    # convert each pair of columns to datetimes
    df.assign(c1 = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'] + ' ' + df['col3']), c2 = pd.to_datetime(df['col4'] + ' ' + df['col5']))
    # groupby consecutive col1 values and keep earliest c1 and latest c2 values
    .groupby(df['col1'].shift().ne(df['col1']).cumsum()).agg({'col1': 'first', 'c1': 'min', 'c2': 'max'})
    # split datetimes back into separate columns by dates and times
    .set_index('col1', append=True).astype(str).stack().str.split(expand=True).unstack()
    # rename columns
    .set_axis(['col2', 'col4', 'col3', 'col5'], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
    # bring col1 in as a column 
    .reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
)
filtered_df
```

[image]